# What are the higher morphisms between enriched higher categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory, higher-category-theory

This question is about $n$-categories, or perhaps $(\infty,n)$-categories, or ...  My guess is that the answer will not depend sensitively on the model of higher categories, so rather than have me force you to work in my favorite model, I ask only that you say with some precision what model you are using, and that your model is not too strict.

You may assume that I have, and am comfortable with, some chosen symmetric monoidal $n$-category $(S,\otimes)$.  I am trying to understand the notion of "($n$-)category enriched in $S$".  By this I would like to mean the following.  Roughly,  $A$ is *enriched in $S$* if $A$ has a set of $0$-morphisms, and between any pair of $0$-morphisms $X,Y \in A$, there is an $S$-object $A(X,Y)$ of 1-morphisms between them.  The composition should be a morphism $A(X,Y) \otimes A(Y,Z) \to A(X,Z)$ in $S$.

I am fairly satisfied that, at least in my example, I can write all of this down explicitly.  Recall that $S$ comes with a chosen object $1 \in S$.  Then the corepresentable functor $S(1,-) : S \to (n-1)\text{-Cat}$ is symmetric monoidal in an essentially unique way.  The usual thing is to use this functor, and define the *de-enrichment* $A_\delta$ of $A$ to be the $n$-category with hom-$(n-1)$-categories given by $A_\delta(-,-) = S(1,A(-,-))$.  Certainly in my example I can work out this $(n-1)$-category.  (De-enrichment is often a highly lossy operation, and I am OK with that.)

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are both $S$-enriched categories.  This is where I start to run into trouble.  I understand what an *$S$-enriched functor* $A \to B$ is.  But I'm having trouble figuring out what is the correct definition of "natural transformation", and in general of the higher morphisms.

> **Question:** Given a symmetric monoidal $n$-category $S$, what is *the $(n+1)$-category* of $S$-enriched ($n$-)categories?  In particular, what are the higher morphisms?

I recognize that this "$(n+1)$-category of $S$-enriched categories" is likely itself enriched in $S$-enriched categories.  But I am interested simply in writing down its de-enrichment — I'm looking for it just as an $(n+1)$-category.

A final remark: The notion of enrichment in this question is not the same as in [n-categories enriched in an (n+1)-category](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102492/n-categories-enriched-in-n1-categories).  That question concerned $n$-categories in which the collection of $n$-morphisms was an object of the enriching category.  I would like the collection of $1$-morphisms to be an object of the enriching category.

Comment: Are you using your assumption that the enriching $n$-category $S$ is symmetric monoidal instead of merely plain monoidal?

Comment: Consider an (n+k)-category $C$ whose 0- though k-morphisms are trivial.  Let $T_m(C)$ denote the (n+k-m)-category obtained by dropping the 0- through (m-1)-morphisms of $C$.  (So the objects of $T_m(C)$ are the m-morphisms of $C$.)  For $k$ large, $T_{k+1}(C)$ is a symmetric monoidal $n$-category; call it $S$.  Now consider $T_k(C)$.  I would be tempted to say that $T_k(C)$ is an (n+1)-category enriched in $S$ in a sense similar to yours.  Does this count as an example of your version of enrichment in $S$, or am I missing something? ...

Comment: ... (continued) If the above makes sense in your context, then can one model the definition of functors, natural transformations, etc. of $S$-enriched categories on the definition of ordinary functors, NTs etc. from $C$ to itself?  Also, does the assumption that $k$ is large play any important role?  Or could we, for example assume that $k=1$?

Comment: @Kevin: The reason I want my enriching $n$-category $S$ to be _symmetric_ monoidal is because then the category of $S$-enriched categories is itself symmetric monoidal, and the motivation for my question comes from a related rinse-and-repeat exercise.  I agree that it is perfectly reasonable to enrich in less-symmetric categories.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For $F,G:C\to D$, an $S$-enriched transformation $F\to G$ will consist of, for each $x\in C$, a morphism $1\to D(F x, G x)$ in $S$, together with for each $x,y\in C$, an equivalence between the composites
$$ C(x,y) \to D(F x, F y) \to D(F y, G y) \otimes D(F x, F y) \to D(F x, G y)$$
and
$$ C(x,y) \to D(G x, G y) \to D(G x, G y) \otimes D(F x, G x) \to D(F x, G y)$$
plus some higher coherence cells until you run out of room.  Does that help?

Comment: Awesome.  Are you aware of anywhere that spells out the higher coherences (e.g. in terms of associahedra)?  I would be interested in e.g. the n=3 case.  Probably I just have to work it out myself.

Comment: Just look at the definition of "tritransformation" in Gordon-Power-Street *Coherence for tricategories* and interpret the diagrams as taking place in $S$ rather than in $Bicat$.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to get the definition of an $S$-transformation, if you know what an $S$-functor is and also the tensor product of $S$-categories (so $S$ must be symmetric) and $S$ has an initial object preserved by $\otimes$ in each variable, is as an $S$-functor

$$ C \otimes \mathbf{2} \to D$$

where $\mathbf{2}$ is the $S$-category with two objects $a$ and $b$, hom-objects $1$ from $a$ to $a$, $b$ to $b$, and $a$ to $b$, and the initial object of $S$ from $b$ to $a$.